# SQL Statement working in client but not within SSIS / Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssis, visual-studio-2019, dateadd, getdate

my script containes this part which runs fine if its commented out.
where dbname.[Date] > DATEADD(month,-1, Getdate())

when i write this it will work in sql client but ssis ole db source will show 0 rows
select * from dbname where dbname.[Date] > DATEADD(month,-1, Getdate())

when i write this it will work in sql client and in ssis
select DATEADD(month,-1, Getdate()) as test from dbname

so the comparison with the > is the problem?

i couldnt find a solution by now

Comment: Inspect the actual value you're getting from your date operation in each environment.
Does the literal match/make sense?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no issue with using a greater than symbol, `>` in a SQL query with and OLE DB Source component in SSIS.

`getdate()` would show "2023-06-29" and *whatever time*. -1 Month makes "2023-05-29". The fact that you get 0 rows means there is no value in the [Date] column that is greater than a month ago. Either the processes aren't populating that column with the current date or there's been no activity for the past month. Or the test you have directly against the client database is not the same source as you have the SSIS package working against.

If I have misunderstood the question, please let me know and edit the question with specific sample structure and data values.